Testing Product Catalog APIs with WhatsApp Messaging
We are building a platform for WhatsApp business messaging. For this, we need to test the product catalog messaging APIs.
However, it seems there is no way to do so without creating a public business account and adding a payment method.
Is there a means to access the APIs without going through the above steps? Especially the payment method as we do not wish to start paying for testing our product before going live.
We have created a product catalog and connected it to the WhatsApp business account on an actual phone number. But we cannot send messages without adding a payment method.
